# Excel: including first row in a filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am considering in particular Excel VBA's AutoFilter method, but I think my question is valid also for the GUI.

When I apply a filter to an Excel worksheet, without selecting anything, the filter applies to all rows *from the second onwards*. Is there any way to include the first row, so that it may be filtered out as well?

Comment: You want to filter out the filter row?

Comment: @GordonBell I'd like to apply a filter to all rows. If I don't do that, I find some difficulties in selecting only the relevant data by VBA.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you can use to see how the filter works:

```
Sub Makro2()

    Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

    With Range("a1")
        .value = "Filter Me"
        .AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

It adds additional row on the first row and then names it "FilterMe". Then it filters. You can read more about [AutoFilter here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx).